# how to list all objects in s3 bucket having having specific character in the key using shell script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a s3 bucket and below is the directory structure.

```
bucketname/uid=/year=/month=/day=/files.parquet
```

In some cases inside year directory I have some temporary object created by athena.Ex:

```
month=11_$folder$
```

I want remove all of these files whose `key = month=11_$folder$`.

Currently I am doing in a loop for all uid. Is there any faster way to do that?

Comment: When you say "Currently I am doing in a loop for all uid" can you clarify what you mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the aws cli [`list-objects-v2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) you can search for patterns

```sh
aws s3api list-objects-v2 \
    --bucket my-bucket \
    --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, `month=11_$folder$`)]'
```

Note this will still query *all* your objects and only filter what is returned back, so if you have more than 1,000 objects in your bucket, you'll need to [paginate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Comment: my key is dynamic like uid=1/year=2020/ so in that how can I define key?